# Kong Gateway Custom Plugin - Errors when redirecting 5xx's to a custom url from header_filter phase

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have custom plugin for the Kong Gateway v3.6.0
During the access phase it may kong.response.exit with a 500 status.
I'm later catching responses with status of 500 during the header_filter phase
(which may come from access or from the service responses)
and changing them to a 307 redirect to a custom error page.

I get the following error:
[error] 37#0: *2378 attempt to set status 500 via ngx.exit after sending out the response status 307

I have tried two different approaches:

using kong.response.exit:

- return kong.response.exit(ngx.HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT, 'redirecting...', { ['Location'] = location_url })*

and just modifying the status and header directly:

- kong.response.set_status(ngx.HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
  kong.response.set_header("Location", location_url)*

both of these result in an functioning redirects to the location_url, but they also litter the kong logs with error messages...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> during the header_filter phase (which may come from access or from the service responses)

header_filter phase is run when all header bytes from the upstream have been received.
I think you cannot call kong.response.exit(...) and on `access` context then
expected to run something on `header_filter` context on the same request since the request will be cut short before proxying to the upstream.

Also, you response of `attempt to set status 500 via ngx.exit after sending out the response status 307` seems like you are ordering the call incorrectly, e.g. calling `kong.response.exit` before calling `kong.response.set_status`.

What is the main purpose of the plugin? `During the access phase it may kong.response.exit with a 500 status` and then `catching responses with status of 500 during the header_filter phase`  seems counter-intuitive for me.
Could you provide the plugin code?